# Including AngularJS with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am learning how to build a Web application (Back :ASP.net and Front : AngularJS). But I cannot display any attribute on the scope. It's look like AngularJS is not recognized by the app on launching.

The program is very simple but I don't know why it does not work.

I am using Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web

BundleConfig.cs :

```
namespace MvcApplication1
{
public class BundleConfig
{
    // For more information on Bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=254725
    public static void RegisterBundles (BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/angular").Include(
            "~/Scripts/angular.js",
            "~/Scripts/angular-route.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

        // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
        // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests 
        you need.
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include("~/Content/site.css"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css").Include(
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.resizable.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.selectable.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.accordion.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.button.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.dialog.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.slider.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.tabs.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.progressbar.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css"));
    }
}
}
```

RouteConfig.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace MvcApplication1
{
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes (RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
}
```

WebApiConfig.cs :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace MvcApplication1
{
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register (HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
}
```

HomeController.cs :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MvcApplication1.Controllers
{
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Home/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

}
}
```

_Layout.cshtml :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body ng-app="MyApp">
@RenderBody()

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@* Add Angular Library Here*@
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/angular")
<script src="~/Scripts/MyApp.js"></script>
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

<div ng-controller="HomeController">{{Message}}</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Home/Index.cshtml :

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<div ng-controller="HomeController">
{{Message}}
</div>
```

The following error message is caughted on chrome console :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYZbT.png)

If need more infos or other files on the project, I am here.

I also wanted to add that I installed AngularJS directly from Nugget Package Manager.

Thank you !

Comment: Have you included the function registerbundles in application_start method? You need to tell mvc explicitly to register the bundles.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The answer is yes. The line BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles); is already on the method Application_Start() from Global.asax.cs file

Comment: I just added the error message that I received on chrome console

Comment: Is jquery loading as expected in the browser? If yes then, can you check your scripts folder if angular script file is there in the given path?

Comment: I resolved the issue. the issue was from ng-Route dependency, I removed it and it worked. Thank a lot !

Comment: The error message was clear, but I didn't think initially to check the console

Comment: Another thing I noticed that you are trying to use angular syntax before you include the angular library. Please check that you are declaring ngapp in the body but you are adding the library after it. I am curious how is it working? As a side note, during web development, always open the dev tools while debugging